# How to feed a network through REST

Tags: python, rest, tensorflow, flask

I'm new to python trying to build an app with TensorFlow. Basically what I need is get features from a loaded neural network, which take around 3 minutes to load.

I would like that my script above load the neural network just once when started and that I could call a rest function just to feed an image to the network.

```
from flask import Flask, request
from flask_restful import Resource, Api

from scipy import misc
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import sys
import os
import argparse

class ImageFeatures(Resource):
    def get(self,img):
        image = misc.imread(os.path.expanduser("Img/Abc_001.jpg"))
        feed_dict = { images_placeholder: image, phase_train_placeholder:False }
        emb = sess.run(embeddings, feed_dict=feed_dict)
        return(emb)

with tf.Graph().as_default():
    with tf.Session() as sess:
        model_dir = 'Model/'
        meta_file, ckpt_file = facenet.get_model_filenames(os.path.expanduser(model_dir))
        facenet.load_model(model_dir, meta_file, ckpt_file)
        images_placeholder = tf.get_default_graph().get_tensor_by_name("input:0")
        embeddings = tf.get_default_graph().get_tensor_by_name("embeddings:0")
        phase_train_placeholder = tf.get_default_graph().get_tensor_by_name("phase_train:0")

print("Rest Running")

app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)
api.add_resource(ImageFeatures, '/getFeatures/<img>')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(port='5002')
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out https://github.com/PipelineAI/pipeline

We package your TensorFlow model (or any type of model) in a REST-based runtime.